# how to use vault protected variables in playbooks

Tags: ansible

I am trying to use the vault for encrypting the sensitive information. Can we use vault protected variables in the playbook tasks.? if yes, can someone please provide some nice examples ??

here is what i have done :

1: created role directory structure

2: created groups_vars/vars file which has following data

> ---
>
> mysql_port: 3306
>
> mysql_host: 10.0.0.3
>
> mysql_user: fred

executed following command to create the encrypted file

> ansible-vault create group_vars/vault

with following data

> ---
>
> vault_ear_password: supersecretpassword

here is the final directory structure

.

├── . . .

├── group_vars/

│   └── database/

│       ├── vars

│       └── vault

└── . . .

now in the group_vars/vars file , i have following entry

> ear_password: "{{ vault_ear_password }}"

now, my query is, cant we use variable {{ear_password}} in the playbook so that i can get value as : supersecretpassword

Comment: What is the _exact_ question? There's a [doc page](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_vault.html) about vault.

Comment: edited the question in detail . please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use variables from vaults this way.

The problem is with your directory structure: you should either place your `vars` and `vault` files into `group_vars/all/` directory if you want this variables to be defined for all hosts, or place them under `group_vars/<group_name>/` directory to define them for specific group (like `database` in your example).

In your current directory structure, variables from `vars` file goes to group with name `vars` and variables from `vault` file goes to group with name `vault`.